# How do I implement an atomic stack with mongoDB and Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to push and pull things off of a stack in an atomic way using ruby and mongoDB.

The push I can do atomically via the following code example:

```
collection.update({"_id" => document["_id"]}, {"$push" => {field_name => value}})
```

Example code for pop:

```
value = collection.update({"_id" => document["_id"]}, {"$pop" => {field_name => -1}})
```

Unfortunately the value returned above is not the value that was 'popped' off the stack.

It seems like a very useful function/feature, and I find it hard to believe this isn't possible with mongoDB.

**Update**

For the benefit of those looking for the complete answer, here it is (Thanks again Cameron):

```
result = collection.find_and_modify({:query => {"_id" => document["_id"]}, :update => {"$pop" => {field_name => -1}}})
return result[field_name][0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want the [`findandmodify` command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findandmodify+Command). This command allows you to modify a document atomically and return the document that was modified. Note that by default, the document returned is the version *before* it was modified. In this case, that is exactly what you want, since you can then get the last item in the stack yourself.

Unfortunately I don't know the Ruby driver, but the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find_and_modify-instance_method) should point you in the right direction syntax-wise.